# How do I have two different routes with the same URL in two different packages in my meteor app?

Tags: rest, meteor, url-routing, activitypub

I'm trying to write an app that uses the ActivityPub standard. Specifically, right now, I'm trying to implement the "[retrieving objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitypub/#retrieving-objects)" part, where a GET request to an objects id with the content header including `application/ld+json; profile="https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams"` or `application/activity+json` will fetch the activitypub representation of that object. However, as it suggests in the article, and as many other activitypub implementations do, I also want to present an HTML page at that URL when the content header asks for HTML.

Furthermore, I want to specify these routes in separate packages - one in the [backend](https://gitlab.com/Agora-Project/backend-core) and one in the [frontend](https://gitlab.com/Agora-Project/frontend-cytoscape), so as to allow different frontends to be written for the same backend. Is this possible? My current investigations would suggest it's not, but I'm not sure yet. Perhaps I need to define the route in the backend, and have it check content header and select response there, but allow the frontend to configure the backend to point to a particular template?

I'm currently using Restivus in the backend and Iron:Router in the frontend, but I'm willing to change both of these if necessary.

Comment: Alright, so I think I have to make the route on the server, check for "accept: text/html", and then render said html with [server render][1]? That's what it's looking like right now, anyway.


  [1]: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/server-render

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but eventually I just made the route in the backend and had it check for `accept: text/html` and if found, redirect it to another route. I'd like to be able to hide the redirect from the client, but this is close enough for now.